# Grails spring security rest plugin v1.5.3 - Refresh token flow

Tags: grails, access-token, jwt, stateless-session, spring-security-rest

I have a REST API implemented using grails v2.5.2 and a client using AngularJS. I am using the JWT authentication that the plugin provides by default.

I've set the token expiration as 3600 and I would like to refresh the access_token automatically (transparently to the user). I know that I have to make a POST to /oauth/access_token with an application/x-www-form-urlencoded and send the refresh_token in order to get a new access_token.

The question I have is:

- What is the status code returned by this plugin when the token expires?
  I set the log4j and I see it is sending a 401 once the token has expired.
  I would expect a 403 instead of a 401 due to the last one is used for invalid login credentials.

I need to know this in order to set up the response interceptor to request a new access_token.

Thank you!